# Main body alignment issue with nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]MY body just wont alight with the nav. there are some margins on the container, when I try to set up mx-0 the space just goes to the left. it is just no taking the whole with of the body. I am not sure what I am missing. I tried putting the nav inside the main container but still doesnt work.

```
 [![<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand px-3">LightQUIZ</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-3 justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">TOP QUIZES</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-start">
        <form class="form-inline mx-lg-2 d-flex flex-row">
          <input class="form-control px-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-success mx-md-2 my-sm-2 my-md-0">LOGIN</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">SIGNUP</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main class="container">
    <section class="home-header row pt-4">
      <div class=" col-md-8 jumbotron">
        <h2 class="display-5">Hello, world!</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to
          featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column">
        <h4 class="text-center">LightQuiz LeaderBoard</h4>
        <ul class="list-group leaderboard">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          ABC
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `container` is so it will add space to either side in case the screen becomes too large in width. Try making your screen really small in width, then resize until it becomes large. It should have breakpoints where the spacing will change.

The `nav` element you have uses other classes that do not change the side spacing the same way as the container.

If you do not want space on either side of you `main` element, simply remove the `container` class.

If you want to make the navbar adopt the same side spacing as the `main` element, add the `container` class to the `nav` element.

---

**Updated** answer after reading your comment here:

Bootstrap also provides a "fluid" container class that makes it span "the entire width of the viewport". From [the latest documentation for version 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#fluid-containers):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: yeah its fixes my issue. I was using row class and col-md- so I thought container class is must in order to use them?

Comment: @special3220 sure. If you want to keep container, try the .container-fluid class. Works for Bootstrap version 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#fluid-containers

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use class `container-fluid` instead of `container` on the main body.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand px-3">LightQUIZ</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-3 justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"> HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">TOP QUIZES</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-start">
        <form class="form-inline mx-lg-2 d-flex flex-row">
          <input class="form-control px-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-success mx-md-2 my-sm-2 my-md-0">LOGIN</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">SIGNUP</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main class="container-fluid">
    <section class="home-header row pt-4">
      <div class=" col-md-8 jumbotron">
        <h2 class="display-5">Hello, world!</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to
          featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column">
        <h4 class="text-center">LightQuiz LeaderBoard</h4>
        <ul class="list-group leaderboard">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            ABC
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">55</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkpu9wcd/

[image]

For more info, read: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/